# 'Too many array/indices error' in substituting data files to equation in python

Tags: python, arrays, iteration, ipython, substitution

I have two separate data sets and I would like to create substitution iteration in data1. There are 100 numbers (not relevant to row number) for data1 which I want to substitute to the function. data2 has numbers for each P and k in each column and their shape is 500*2. So what I basically want to do is substitute one value from data1 for whole arrays of data2 (so 500 numbers for given number from data1) then sum all those numbers and return to result; then iterate until the row number x reaches 100 and collect all those results in array.
I have running following code in ipython, and it gives me 'too many array' error message..

I don't know how to resolve this... please help

```
data1 = np.genfromtxt('text.txt')
data2 = np.genfromtxt('cambPB.txt')
r = data1[:,0]
P = data2[:,1]
k = data2[:,0]

for x in r:
    result = []
    x = 1
    if x < 101:
        xi = P*(np.sin(k*r[x,0])-k*s*np.cos(k*r[x,0]))/(2*(np.pi*r[x,0])**2)
        y = np.sum(xi)
        result.append(y)
        x = x+1
        print result
        break
```

ADDED: shape of data1 is 100*4 and shape of data2 is 500*2

Comment: I was selecting the first column of data. And r [x,0] meant to be specific position in data1 array.. but probably wrong

Comment: @LutzHorn that is valid syntax for `numpy` arrays.

Comment: `r[x,0]` inside your function probably doesn't do what you want, since `r` is not an index (or perhaps it does, if `r` is an array of indices; I can't tell).

Comment: What are the shapes of of `data1` and `data2`; your wording is a bit unclear, just give the shapes.

Comment: Could you add the proper, full traceback?